# Exception adding my own row to a DataGridView with text and combo values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am now pulling my hair out with this. I could not work out how to do it using a DataSource so I decided a more manual approach.

I have some XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<GenioCodes>
  <Code Layer="BI" Colour="1" />
  <Code Layer="BP" Colour="1" />
  <Code Layer="BS" Colour="1" />
  <Code Layer="C" Colour="1" />
  <Code Layer="CC" Colour="1" />
  <Code Layer="CR" Colour="1" />
</GenioCodes>
```

I have a custom cell value:

```
public class ComboboxColorItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ushort Index { get; set; }
    public Color Value { get; set; }

    public ComboboxColorItem(string Name, ushort Index, Color Value)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Index = Index;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    static public ComboboxColorItem Create(ushort iColourIndex)
    {
        OdCmColor oColour = new OdCmColor();

        oColour.setColorIndex(iColourIndex);

        CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

        String strColour = textInfo.ToTitleCase(oColour.colorNameForDisplay());
        if (iColourIndex > 7)
            strColour = String.Format("Colour {0}", iColourIndex);
        ComboboxColorItem oColorItem = new ComboboxColorItem(
            strColour,
            iColourIndex,
            Color.FromArgb(oColour.red(), oColour.green(), oColour.blue()));

        oColour.Dispose();

        return oColorItem;
    }
}
```

I read the XML file and try to add it to a table:

```
private void GENIO_Code_Editor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        buttonDetect.Enabled = m_dbDatabase != null;

        cboColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cboColumn.Name = "Color";
        cboColumn.DataPropertyName = "ComboboxColorItem";
        cboColumn.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cboColumn.ValueMember = "Value";

        List<ushort> listColors = new List<ushort>();
        listColors.Add(1);
        listColors.Add(2);
        listColors.Add(3);
        listColors.Add(4);
        listColors.Add(5);
        listColors.Add(6);
        listColors.Add(7);
        listColors.Add(8);
        listColors.Add(9);
        listColors.Add(250);
        listColors.Add(251);
        listColors.Add(252);
        listColors.Add(253);
        listColors.Add(254);
        listColors.Add(255);

        foreach (ushort iColorIndex in listColors)
            cboColumn.Items.Add(ComboboxColorItem.Create(iColorIndex));

        //this.DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cboColumn);

        dataGridView.Columns.Add("Layer", "Layer");
        dataGridView.Columns.Add(cboColumn);

        if (textBoxXML.Text != "")
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(textBoxXML.Text);
            XmlNodeList listCodes = doc.SelectNodes("GenioCodes/Code");

            foreach(XmlNode oCode in listCodes)
            {
                int iRow = dataGridView.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView.Rows[iRow].Cells["Layer"].Value = oCode.Attributes["Layer"].Value;

                ComboboxColorItem ocbItem = ComboboxColorItem.Create(Convert.ToUInt16(oCode.Attributes["Colour"].Value));
                dataGridView.Rows[iRow].Cells["Color"].Value = ocbItem;

                //dataGridView.Rows.Add(oCode.Attributes["Layer"].Value, 
                //                      ComboboxColorItem.Create(Convert.ToUInt16(oCode.Attributes["Colour"].Value)));
            }
            /*
            m_dataSet.ReadXml(textBoxXML.Text);
            dataGridView.DataSource = m_dataSet.Tables[0];
            */
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

    }
}
```

But it is giving me a nightmare. I keep getting a dataError exception for the combo cells when the rows are added. I tried handling RowsAdded but I could not yet access the cells on that row.

The context of the exception is **Formatting | Display**. But I already have handlers. eg:

```
private void dataGridView_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cell Parsing " + e.ColumnIndex.ToString());

    if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name != "Color")
        return;

    foreach (ComboboxColorItem item in cboColumn.Items)
    {
        if (item.Name == (string)e.Value)
        {
            e.Value = item;
            e.ParsingApplied = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!e.ParsingApplied)
    {
        ComboboxColorItem ocbItem = ComboboxColorItem.Create((ushort)e.Value);
        cboColumn.Items.Add(ocbItem);
        e.Value = ocbItem;
        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

But this error is raised **before** the parsing. What to do?

The error is raised when I try to add a row into the table (see Load event).

Exception from DataError:

```
-       e   {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs}   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs
        Cancel  false   bool
        ColumnIndex 1   int
        Context Formatting | Display    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts
+       Exception   {"DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid."}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
        RowIndex    0   int
        ThrowException  false   bool
        cancel  false   bool
        columnIndex 1   int
        context Formatting | Display    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorContexts
+       exception   {"DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid."}    System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}
        rowIndex    0   int
        throwException  false   bool
+       Static members
```

The error seems to be raised before the cell is formatted. But it does continue and populate the cell OK. Buf I keep getting the error. Even after cells are added (like, when the form is just repainting). In fact, the error is before even the CellFormatting / CellPainting.

Update: It is NOT caused when adding the rows. I can debug trace all the row adding calls. It must be after this when the grid is displaying.

Update: Further to the answer provided .... Thanks!

I had to change this code:

```
cboColumn.ValueMember = "Value";
```

to:

```
cboColumn.ValueMember = "Name";
```

Then I had to adjust my parsing event handler to use:

```
if(item.Name == (string)e.Value)
```

I tried leaving the ValueMember set as **Value** and casting e.Value to (Color) but it raised an exception. The IDE was showing "255, 0, 0" for example. So I changed to the string property instead.

Then I did what you suggested in the answer:

```
dataGridView.Columns.Add("Layer", "Layer");
dataGridView.Columns.Add(cboColumn);

if (textBoxXML.Text != "")
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(textBoxXML.Text);
    XmlNodeList listCodes = doc.SelectNodes("GenioCodes/Code");

    foreach(XmlNode oCode in listCodes)
    {
        int iRow = dataGridView.Rows.Add();

        dataGridView.Rows[iRow].Cells["Layer"].Value = oCode.Attributes["Layer"].Value;

        ushort iColourIndex = Convert.ToUInt16(oCode.Attributes["Colour"].Value);
        ComboboxColorItem ocbItem2 = null;
        foreach(ComboboxColorItem ocbItem in cboColumn.Items)
        {
            if (ocbItem.Index == iColourIndex)
            {
                ocbItem2 = ocbItem;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(ocbItem2 == null)
        {
            ocbItem2 = ComboboxColorItem.Create(iColourIndex);
            cboColumn.Items.Add(ocbItem2);
        }
        dataGridView.Rows[iRow].Cells["Color"].Value = ocbItem2;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this lines

```
ComboboxColorItem ocbItem = ComboboxColorItem.Create(Convert.ToUInt16(oCode.Attributes["Colour"].Value));
dataGridView.Rows[iRow].Cells["Color"].Value = ocbItem;
```

`ocbItem` is a new instance of ComboboxColorItem, which doesn't belong to `Items`, and DataGridViewComboBoxCell doesn't accept it as a valid value.

possible workarounds:

1. find appropriate item in `Items` collection and use it as a cell value

or

2. override `Equals` of `ComboboxColorItem` class

Comment: Ah! Cool. Thanks. See my updated question with comments. In addition, I was not sure how to use this override of Equals. Can my code be simplified?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, updated part with `ocbItem2` looks correct to me.